# Прогнозирование

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, временные-ряды

Изучаю прогнозирование временных рядов. Столкнулся с вопросом: как построить долгосрочный прогноз по малому количеству данных (всего 60 точек, прогноз нужен на 40 вперед, что скорее всего просто смешно).

Пробую ARIMA, но прогноз просто ужас.

Есть идея связать начальные данные с коррелирующими данными, построив прогноз по коррелирующим данным, строить уже прогноз по своим данным. Мне нужен совет по литературе в данной теме и если такое кто-то, когда-то делал до меня, то как это называется в мире науки.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: А точки какие? Просто может там хоть какая-то сезонность есть. Одно дело точки за день, а другое, например, за несколько лет за одни и те же дни. Но, конечно, мало точек - это плохо. Так то это `time series` называется такой тип задач. По ленивому варианту можно `Facebook Prophet` попробовать.

Comment: `всего 60 точек, прогноз нужен на 40 вперед` - в мире науки это имеет много названий - "гадание на кофейной гуще", "работа с магическим кристаллом", "гадание на картах таро" и т.д.  Если серьезно - уловить "сезонность" и "тренд" на таком количестве данных просто нереально.

Comment: @MaxU Не, ну построить то можно, если нужно, но тогда нужно строить не только прогноз, но и возможное отклонение, и оно там будет расходиться с каждой точкой довольно сильно )

Comment: @CrazyElf, построить можно и по двум точкам на 1000 точек вперед - а смысл? :-D

Comment: @MaxU Смысла вообще ни в чём нет, но если деньги платят, то почему бы и не сделать )  Вот если не платят, тогда другое дело ))

Comment: @CrazyElf данные (потребление нефти в общей электрогенерации по годам с 1960 по 2021). Сезонности нет, имеется в некоторых странах тренд, но тоже не везде.

Comment: ох, строить прогнозы на таких данных (одна точка в год) - неблагодарное дело. Особенно на 40 лет вперед )

Comment: @new_user Ну, я думаю, вы действительно тогда можете попробовать найти, с чем ваши точечные данные хорошо коррелируют, спрогнозировать эти коррелирующие данные и вернуться обратно к прогнозу точек. Но помните, что ложные корреляции тоже бывают, и да, эта область называется "большие данные", а для маленького кол-ва данных степень уверенности прогноза будет просто никакая.

Comment: @MaxU Хотя, если воспринимать эти данные как некий аггрегат за год, то почему бы и нет. По-моему стоит попытаться. Вот если бы это были почасовые или поминутные данные - всё было бы гораздо хуже )

Comment: @CrazyElf, попытаться конечно стоит, но я бы не ожидал сколько-нибудь толкового прогноза)

Comment: @new_user, у вас учебное задание или делаете прогноз каким-то заказчикам?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вам тут коллеги уже подсказали - строить прогноз на 40 точек вперед, имея 60 точек ретроданных - занятие по сути малоперспективное, а если учесть, что это экономический прогноз - то и попросту безсмысленное. За сорок лет может произойти пять экономических кризиса, два нефтяных, три раза измениться технология добычи, законодательная отмена ДВС и три революции в придачу. Какой тут прогноз.

А вот на пару тройку лет - вполне. Такие задачи обычные при кратко и среднесрочном экономическом анализе. Поэтому из литературы могу посоветовать в первую очередь обратиться к книгам по Эконометрике. Их есть много и разных. Там и примеры подходящие найдете и на рекомендации всякие посмотрите, подсказки -  когда какие из методов применять. И кстати, с удивлением можно обнаружить, что современные, навороченные методы анализа для таких задач довольно часто оказываются не лучше, чем устоявшихся классические методы (то-же сглаживание). Там-же рассматриваются задачи прогнозирования со многими предикторными переменными, а также т.н. панельные данные *(это к вопросу "связать начальные данные с коррелирующими данными")*

Ну, например:

```
Вербик М. Путеводитель по современной эконометрике.
Доугерти К. Введение в эконометрику  --- считается классикой
Мангус Я.П. Эконометрика Начальный курс 
Носко В.П. Эконометрика для начинающих. Дополнительные главы --- серьёзное чтиво.
Орлов А.И. Эконометрика. Учебник (Учебник для вузов) 
Суслов В.И. Эконометрия.
Светуньков С.Г.Методы и модели социально-экономического прогнозирования учебник -  в двух томах.
```

Можете еще попробовать посмотреть вот в такой неплохой книжечке:

```
Четыркин Е.М. Статистические методы прогнозирования
```

Но чуда не ждите. Даже краткосрочный прогноз в экономике как правило имеет очень широкий доверительный интервал за счет малого количества исходных данных. А про 40 лет -  лучше и вовсе забыть.
Удачи.

Comment: Пессимистичный взгляд. По крайней мере авторы [этого исследования](https://www.csr-nw.ru/files/csr/file_content_55.pdf) с вами вряд ли согласятся. Понятно, что они использовали в своем прогнозе много факторов, но imho если внимательно посмотреть на их графики, то можно прикинуть, какую регрессию положить в основу подходящего прогноза для данных ТС

Comment: @ 
avp
"— Я духов вызывать могу из бездны!
— И я могу, и всякий это может. Вопрос лишь, явятся ль они на зов.
Уильям Шекспир,  «Генрих IV»."  Это я к тому, что "напрогнозировать" то можно всякого. Но результат соответствует названию. "Гадание на кофейной гуще". С точки зрения реальной науки так не делается, потому как первым шагом надо доказать адекватность модели, а уж потом что-то прогнозировать.  Но как красивые картинки для какого-то доклада на какой-нибудь общественно-политической-маркетинговой конференции - вполне сгодиться. Один график-прогноз на стр.12 чего стоит.

Comment: Доказать адекватность модели -- это, конечно, правильно. Но чисто интуитивно потребление нефти останется пропорционально численности населения (ее доля в выработке электричества несколько упадет, но все хотят жить лучше, поэтому электричества на душу надо будет больше). Население за 40 лет вырастет процентов на 20, вот также вырастет и количество потребляемой электростанциями нефти

Comment: @passant спасибо за рекомендации книг, это очень полезная информация, и за такой развернутый ответ.

Comment: @avp а запрет на выпуск автомобилей с ДВС игнорируем? А возрастание использования возобновляемой энергетики? А использование водорода? Все это факторы, не поддающиеся учету. И таких за "40 лет вперед" может быть еще не один. Просто лично для меня прогноз это то, чему  "доказательно" можно верить. Не даром в теории прогнозирования есть понятие - горизонт прогнозирования -  это такой период, когда доверительный интервал прогноза остается в приемлемых границах. А все остальное - это уже "пророчество". Верить ему или нет -  личное дело каждого.

Comment: @passant, не буду спорить (особенно о влиянии запретов ДВС на *общее* потребление электроэнергии, ее роль в технологии получения водорода и т.п.). Только лишь обращу ваше внимание на такую простую и универсальную штуку, как *законы сохранения*